# I am trying to install a pakage vifp by using the command pip install vifp

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install a pakage vifp by using the command
pip install vifp 
but it coulf not make it, it showing a error like

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vifp (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vifp

how to clear it ??

Comment: Would you happen to have a link to the actual package? `vifp` does not appear to be hosted on pypi.org so that explains the error message you are looking at.

Comment: Like @metatoaster said, do you have a link for this package?

Comment: @metatoaster sorry i don't have any link for this pakage...but in my code there is import function for vifp

Answer (score 0):

There is no python package with name vifp.
if there is an import for vifp in the code, there may be an **script with name vifp.py** in your code directory and the code is using that.

I think there is a package with name **sewar** that supports vifp, i you want to write the code on your own.